How to identify an error in JSON+LD in header of WordPress site
When I do a URL inspection using Google Search Console, it keeps identifying an error in this custom code an SEO guy we hired put on our site through a plugin. I identified and fixed the first error, but now keep getting "Parsing error: Missing '}' or object member name".
Search Console is not highlighting the problem code this time, like it did for that last error. Why am I getting this error? It seems to indicate the problem occurs twice, at the bottom of each "sameAs" block. The custom code is:
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "MedicalBusiness",
  "name": "Sirona Therapy",
  "image": "https://www.sironatherapies.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/header.png",
  "@id": "",
  "url": "https://www.sironatherapies.com",
  "telephone": "(914) 241-0727",
  "priceRange": "$",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "280 N Bedford Rd #301",
    "addressLocality": "Mount Kisco",
    "addressRegion": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10549",
    "addressCountry": "US"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": 41.2178324,
    "longitude": -73.71753639999997
  },
  "openingHoursSpecification": [{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday"
    ],
    "opens": "09:30",
    "closes": "19:30"
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
    "opens": "10:00",
    "closes": "15:00"
  }],
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/sironatherapywestchester/",
    "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3kADQ4Bobe1VqoBWt8iLjQ",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/company/sirona-therapy/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/sironatherapywestchester/"
  ],
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "Jennifer L Zauner LCSWR",
  "url": "https://www.sironatherapies.com/",
  "image": "https://www.sironatherapies.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/DSCF8021-200x200.jpg",
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/sironatherapywestchester/",
    "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3kADQ4Bobe1VqoBWt8iLjQ",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/company/sirona-therapy/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/sironatherapywestchester/"
  ],
  "jobTitle": "Owner",
  "worksFor": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Sirona Therapy"
  },
}
</script>

I originally identified that a comma was missing at the end of the third URL in the sameAs section. When I added that, the "Parsing error: Missing ',' or ']' in array declaration" error finally went away, but was replaced with this new error.

JSON doesn't allow trailing comma in an object or array, which you do have here. Anyways, the usual good practice is to use linters, e.g. https://jsonlint.com.

Thank you β.εηοιτ.βε. I should have prefaced everything with explaining that I'm barely knowledgeable about JSON or coding. I am technical, and I'm trying to help my wife with her website. I can examine what is already there and see if something was left out. That's how I fixed the previous error. But, I'm not understanding what you're explaining to me. Would you please tell me exactly where in the script there are trailing commas in the object or array. Thank you.

Other than the trailing commas, it appears to be well-formed.
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "MedicalBusiness",
  "name": "Sirona Therapy",
  "image": "https://www.sironatherapies.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/header.png",
  "@id": "",
  "url": "https://www.sironatherapies.com",
  "telephone": "(914) 241-0727",
  "priceRange": "$",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "280 N Bedford Rd #301",
    "addressLocality": "Mount Kisco",
    "addressRegion": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10549",
    "addressCountry": "US"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": 41.2178324,
    "longitude": -73.71753639999997
  },
  "openingHoursSpecification": [
    {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": [
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday"
      ],
      "opens": "09:30",
      "closes": "19:30"
    },
    {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
      "opens": "10:00",
      "closes": "15:00"
    }
  ],
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/sironatherapywestchester/",
    "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3kADQ4Bobe1VqoBWt8iLjQ",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/company/sirona-therapy/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/sironatherapywestchester/"
  ]  <---you had one here
}

{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "Jennifer L Zauner LCSWR",
  "url": "https://www.sironatherapies.com/",
  "image": "https://www.sironatherapies.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/DSCF8021-200x200.jpg",
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/sironatherapywestchester/",
    "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3kADQ4Bobe1VqoBWt8iLjQ",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/company/sirona-therapy/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/sironatherapywestchester/"
  ],
  "jobTitle": "Owner",
  "worksFor": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Sirona Therapy"
  }  <---you had one here
}


Errors are finally gone. You're the best brother!
